# WordPRess - Getting my blog to show up in more than one location

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble wrapping my head around getting my blog to show up in more than one location. Essentially I want the contents from the blog to show up on a blog page, but also, to have excerpts from the blog show up on my front, static page. Normally I would use get_page_by_title to grab content from a page, when I want to grab content from two different locations and put it on a single page... But I am having trouble understanding how I can do this with the index page... Or how I would make the blog show up on more than one location...

I hope I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: You may be better off asking on [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com). But basically, I'd suggest making a custom page template for your static front page, setting your chosen front page to use that template, then coding the template to use a custom Loop to pull and display whatever you want there.

Comment: thank you. this helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Given that my comment helped out, and the question's stayed open, I'll formalise it as answer.

The way I'd do this is:

- Create a custom page template for your static front page.
- Make sure your chosen front page is set to use this custom page template.
- Put whatever loop(s) you want into the custom template. Generally, what I do is:
- - Use the normal page loop to grab the content of the static front page and output it, so you can edit the page content as normal. I'll usually just steal the code for this from an existing template's `page.php` as a basis.
- - Add a second loop to loop through whatever content you want, e.g. use `query_posts` to reset the loop and grab the latest five blog posts and output them as an excerpt with a featured image, say. The Codex section on [Multiple Loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops) goes into detail on how to add a second loop to a page.